# Python3 not recogninzing face_recognition as a module

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, face-recognition

I am trying to use the implement the face_recognition module, so far without success. When I try to run it with an import in python it just says that there is no such module, however when i just try to run face_recognition on it's own it works just fine.

Comment: You should give us more information i.e. enough to be able to reproduce the problem you are facing. you may benefit from reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Case 1: Same directory name

Maybe your main folder name is `face_recognition`. If that's the case, then try to change it because if you try to import it, the python will import it from your main folder rather than importing it from the package folder.

#### Case 2: Permission

If you're using Linux, then make sure that the package folder is accessible. To verify that this the issue, try to run the program with elevated privileges using `sudo` command. You can try using the `--user` flag with `pip` (`pip install face_recognition --user`).

#### Case 3: Environment variables

It might be the case that your environment variables are not updated. May reference to the package folder is not present. That's why your python interpreter is unable to find the package. For path details:

```py
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Using this, you will get an idea of whether your interpreter searches for the package or not.